# Android Custom Font: Setting it globally does not make it work for Listviews

Tags: android, listview, fonts

In my android app, I have set a custom font globally in the application file.

FontsOverride.java

```
public class FontsOverride {

public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
                                  String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
    final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            fontAssetName);
    replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
}

protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
                                  final Typeface newTypeface) {
    try {
        final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
        staticField.setAccessible(true);
        staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

In the class extending Application,

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", "fonts/GOTHAMRND-BOOK.OTF");
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT_BOLD", "fonts/GOTHAMRND-BOLD.OTF");
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", "fonts/GOTHAMRND-BOOK.OTF");
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SANS_SERIF", "fonts/GOTHAMRND-BOOK.OTF");
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SERIF", "fonts/GOTHAMRND-BOOK.OTF");

}
```

Also I have created a folder under main, named "assets" and another folder named "fonts" under "assets". It contains all the font files referenced.

With this, the font is getting applied everywhere, except listviews, expandable listviews and gridviews.

Is there anything I am missing ? Why is specifically not working for listviews, expandable listviews and gridviews. I tried adding typeface in styles.xml as:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
</style>
```

Can anybody help me in this ? I dont want to hardcode the typeface in the textview in list via list adapter, because that diminishes performance and ends up taking a lot of CPU usage. Also it effects smoothness of scrolling for long lists and if this list is in a viewpager, it really affects the viewpager swiping smoothness.

Comment: try calligraphy it is cool lib   https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: "I have set a custom font globally in the application file" -- note that this approach may not work on all Android devices, due to differences in Android based on OS versions or device manufacturer/ROM developer changes. "because that diminishes performance and ends up taking a lot of CPU usage" -- not if you do it correctly.